# Загрузка изображения OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Я новичок в OpenCV.
Работаю на Windows 10, VS 2019.

Устанавливала библиотеку OpenCV по инструкции с официально сайта. Так же чисто скопировала пример с оф. документации, но функция `imread()` не загружает картинку.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 char* imageName = argv[1];
 Mat image;
 image = imread( imageName, IMREAD_COLOR );
 if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
 {
   printf( " No image data \n " );
   return -1;
 }

 Mat gray_image;
 cvtColor( image, gray_image, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
 imwrite( "../../images/Gray_Image.jpg", gray_image );
 namedWindow( imageName, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 namedWindow( "Gray image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 imshow( imageName, image );
 imshow( "Gray image", gray_image );
 waitKey(0);
 return 0;
}
```

Так же очень странно, что функция `namedWindow( "Gray image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );` каждый новый запуск отображает окно с разными китайскими иероглифами в заголовке, вместо **"Gray image"**.

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Приложение пытаетесь запустить в студии? Функция выводит мусор, по этому и иероглифы.

Comment: @B1aZe да, в студии. Но почему она выводит мусор, если этот пример из документации?

Comment: программу нужно скомпилировать и перетащить на исполняемый файл изображение. Пока вы не перетащите изображение, `char* imageName = argv[1]` будет принимать мусор в памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Почему не загружает картинку и варианты решения.

1. Ты можешь указать название файла который будешь читать вот так

```
 image = imread( 'image.jpg', IMREAD_COLOR );
```

или через путь к диску

```
 image = imread( 'C:путь к папке.. /image.jpg', IMREAD_COLOR );
```

2. Так как сейчас у тебя написано так

```
 char* imageName = argv[1];
 Mat image;
 image = imread( imageName, IMREAD_COLOR );
```

то название изображения он ждет в командной строке, по этому что бы заработало так как есть нужно
a) запускать добавляя название изображения через аргументы функции при запуске в студии.
б) Или с коммандной строки запускать

```
Твое приложение.exe ./image.jpg
```

в) или в свойствах екзешника добавить аргумент image.jpg

Проще пропиши как в пункт 1, спрашивай если будут вопросы)